# Inverse elements in a certain monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and $Z(R_R)$ be its right singular ideal, i.e. the set of elements of $R$ whose right annihilators are essential in the right module $R_R$.

My question:

If $x\in Z(R_R)$, is there an element $y\in R$ with $y+x+yx=0$?

It is easy to see that when $1+x$ is a unit in $R$ ( for example, when $x\in Z(R_R)$ is nilpotent, which is the case whenever $R$ has the ascending chain condition on  right annihilators of elements ) such a $y$ exists.

Thanks for any suggestion or help!

Comment: Your title is very mysterious considering the contents of the body of the post. Perhaps you'd like to let readers in on the secret monoid?

Comment: @rschwieb When $R$ is a ring (possibly without unity), one could define an operation $*$ between the elements of $R$ as: $y*x=y+x+yx$ with $0_R$ as the identity so that $(R,*)$ is a monoid.

Comment: I think even better yet, you can show that in a Dedekind finite ring (one in which one-sided inverses are two-sided) $1+x$ is a unit iff $x$ a unit with the operation $x\circ y=xy+x+y$. If memory serves, ACC on right annihilators implies DF. Currently I'm not sure I know a ring which is not right nonsingular and not DF. Perhaps the product of two negative examples will give me what I want... or maybe not

Comment: And of course, no matter what, $x$ is a unit with respect to $\circ$ iff $(1+x)$ is a unit with respect to the original multiplication. I haven't seen a link so far to the singular ideal.